# changing background image is not responsive

Tags: css, css-transitions

so i'm trying to change background-image using css transition,
i have a problem which is that the img is not responsive this way
can any one help me come up with a way it would be 100% height and width?

```
.container{
  width:100%;
  height:600px;

}

.container img, .top{
    max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}

.top{
  width:100%;
    height:300px;
   -webkit-transition: background-image 0.5s;
    display:block;
}

.top:before{
  content: "";
  background-image:url(https://sc02.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1ZRbgIVXXXXXTXXXXq6xXFXXX9/600-x-600-mm-egyptian-tile-keramik.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
   -webkit-transition: background 0.5s;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  display:block;
}

.container:hover .top:before {
    content: "";
    background-image: url(http://www.jokopost.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%A1-commons.wikimedia.org_.png);
    -webkit-transition: background 1s;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}


<div class="container">
<div class="top">
</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7ejtydts/2/

Answer (score 1):

Using "background-size: contain;" will make the image responsive, but it will not stretch it beyond its dimensions. So the example you have posted, is responsive, but only if you make the container smaller.

Using "background-size: cover;" will make the image stretch to the size of the container. This has the disadvantage that it will cut the edges off the image if the container is not the same ratio.

Have a look at my updated fiddle here:

```
.container{
  width:600px;
  height:600px;

}

.container img, .top{
    max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}

.top{
  width:600px;
    height:400px;
   -webkit-transition: background-image 0.5s;
    display:block;
}

.top:before{
  content: "";
  background-image:url(https://sc02.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1ZRbgIVXXXXXTXXXXq6xXFXXX9/600-x-600-mm-egyptian-tile-keramik.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
   -webkit-transition: background 0.5s;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  display:block;
}

.container:hover .top:before {
    content: "";
    background-image: url(http://www.jokopost.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%A1-commons.wikimedia.org_.png);
    -webkit-transition: background 1s;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7ejtydts/3/

Comment: You could look at using a real image instead of background image, or you can use a background image but make sure the container has fixed width/height ratio. Alternatively, you can use background images with plenty of space around the edges, so that you can cut bits off and it not look any different.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it will adjust the responsiveness of the image.

```
.top::before {
    background-image: url("https://sc02.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1ZRbgIVXXXXXTXXXXq6xXFXXX9/600-x-600-mm-egyptian-tile-keramik.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.top {
    display: block;
    height: 600px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```